# How do I convert a javascript object to structured jsonb in Postgres?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, object, jsonb

If I have a plain `js` object like this in my application layer:

```js
{ name: 'amit', age: 44, likes: ['some', 'things']}
```

I would just do a JSON.stringify on it to get:

```json
"{"name":"amit","age":44,"likes":["some","things"]}"
```

But I want to do this in sql in my postgres db which has a `jsonb` column.

I have tried using functions like `to_json` (which fails) and also tried casting this object like so:

```sql
SELECT '{ name: 'amit', age: 44, likes: ['some', 'things']}'::jsonb
```

But this gives me an error:

```
ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "', age: 44, likes: ['"
LINE 8: SELECT '{ name: 'amit', age: 44, likes: ['some', 'things']}'.
```

How do I convert this object to a structured jsonb object which I can store in my table's `jsonb` column?

Comment: You've already given the answer yourself: `JSON.stringify`. You need to send valid JSON to postgres, not a js syntax object literal.

Comment: Btw, if you've actually got an *object* in your application layer, how did you make that into the string `'{ name: 'amit', age: 44, likes: ['some', 'things']}'` in the first place?

Comment: I am just playing around in the sql console and wanted a helper function available to me for parsing and stringifying objects into jsonb objects and vice versa

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. There are no js objects in an sql console. The function for stringifying objects into jsonb format is `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: You are right. I was going about this the wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong syntax :). Postgres is not JavaScript. Postgres json syntax is more closer to Python's dictionaries (keys need to be quoted). Use double quotes for the keys and string values instead of single quotes. Then use `::jsonb` to convert that to proper jsonb format.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is fine for this purpose, I don't know why your select is wrong.

Your select should be:

`SELECT '{ "name": "amit", "age": 44, "likes": ["some", "things"]}'::jsonb;`

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ name: 'amit', age: 44, likes: ['some', 'things']}));
```